# Pandas TypeError bad operand type for unary ~: 'list', Python 3.10.1

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of the dataset where I have getting this error.
In the first row there are 2x times the `value` of `'Week'`.
What I wanted to do is.

1. Look in the first row check every cell if the `value` `'Week'` exist .
2. Make a `Boolean` list of cells that has the `value` `'Week'`.
3. Remove the columns.

.

```
import pandas as pdtest

dftest = pd.DataFrame([*zip(['Week','Total','Total'],
                            [4,685,633],
                            ['2017-01-23 00:00:00',369.37913186561053,341.67926027078333],
                            ['2017-01-24 00:00:00',349.89972501652701,340.126939283226434],
                            ['2017-01-28 00:00:00',353.74896050667999,314.016037939271868],
                            [5,675,619],
                            ['Week','Total','Total']
                            )])

    df2 = ~dftest.iloc[0].isin(['Week', 'Total']).tolist()
```

When I try to invert the `Boolean` list with tilde `~` I get this error. I can use `Numpy` invert to solve it, but I'm not sure why the tilde is not working.

```
b = np.invert(df2)
b[0] = True  ## Skip first column
df = df.iloc[:,b ]
```

End result

```
     0      1           2           3           4  5  
1  Week     4  2017-01-23  2017-01-24  2017-01-28  5
2  Total  685  369.379132  349.899725  353.748961  675
3  Total  633  341.679260  340.126939  314.016038  619
```

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to check only in the first row and return `True` / `False` for whether the value is 'Week' or 'Total'.

To do that with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), you can slightly rewrite your code to this, which returns your expectation:

```
dftest.iloc[0,:].isin(['Week','Total'])

0     True    # --> Column 0 contains either Week or Total
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True   # --> Column 6 contains either Week or Total
```

Then you can use your `~`

To your your new filtered dataframe, you can wrap it in [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which which can be used with a boolean array:

```
df2 = dftest.loc[~dftest.iloc[0,:].isin(['Week','Total'])]

print(df2)

       0    1           2           3           4    5      6
1  Total  685  369.379132  349.899725  353.748961  675  Total
2  Total  633  341.679260  340.126939  314.016038  619  Total
```

Comment: Hi thanks, i have edit my msg where the end result should be. Shouldn't remove the row but the column. It's strange that you need to wrap the tilde in loc